# Removing the sub-document from the array by id and curent user restriction

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I've got a Messages collection with objects like this:

```
{
    "_id": ...,
    "author": 123,
    "body": "merp",
    "comments": [
        {
            "_id": ...,
            "author": 234,
            "body": "But what about morp?"
        },
        {
            "_id": ...,
            "author": 123,
            "body": "You're out of your element, Donnie!"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm creating those `comment._id`s myself when adding them. Anyway, everything works fine, I found out how to add and delete stuff from the comments array etc.

Except now when deleting a comment, I want to check first if the `author` is the current user. In Meteor, usually you pass the object id to a Meteor-method, which then checks the object and decides whether it's ok to execute. E.g. to delete a message, my method looks like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  deleteMessage: function(messageId) {
    message = Messages.findOne(messageId);

    if(!message) {
      throw new Meteor.Error("not-found");
    }
    if(Meteor.userId() != message.author) {
      throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
    }

    Messages.remove(messageId);
  }
});
```

Now how would I do the same for `comment` objects? I suppose I will have to pass both `messageId` and `commentId`, which is not a problem, but then how do I do the permission check? I can't just get a single `comment` object by `_id`, can I? At least I've been trying to google this but failed. Should I first retrieve the `message` object, then manually look through it's comments array to find the one with the correct `_id`?

**So to make this more clear**: I know how to use `$pull` to delete `comment` objects by `_id`, what I'm looking for is how do I check whether the object exists in the first place, and that its `author` is the current user?

**Disclaimer**: I'm new to Mongo and am fighting the urge to put the comment objects in its own collection, relational-style. From what I've read you're supposed to put everything into one big document. It could well be that I'm missing a crucial point here and in case you see it please point it out to me, even if it does not answer the original question. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove an item from the array then you want to use the [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator with [`.update()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update)

```
Messages.update(
   { 
       "_id": messageId, 
       "comments._id": commentId,
       "comments.author": Meteor.userId()
   },
   { "$pull": { "comments": { "_id": commentId } } }
)
```

Optionally look for the presence of the "comments._id" as well in the query statement to avoid a match if that comment has already been removed by another request.

To clarify the "method inside the query argument", this is JavaScript, so any `function()` is evaluated into the object sytax with it's returned value. So before the `.update()` is executed the `Meteor.userId()` value is commited with it's return value.

The `$pull` operator works like a query condition in itself, and will remove any elements matching the conditions from the array. You could also include the same "author" check in there, but it's not really necessary.

Comment: Thanks! As mentioned, I already know how to delete objects from the comments array. The problem is how do I check if the `author` of the `comment` is the current user? I edited the question to make this more clear

Comment: @cpury Missed that line in the query when typing. This is nice to have in your API, but generally you should make your front end not allow the "click" action of a delete for a comment that is not theirs as well. But that is another question.

Comment: Right, the delete button is not displayed in the frontend, but for security I do need to check in the backend as well.

Thanks for your updated answer, that is very close to what I want. I guess I don't _have to_ to check for "not-found" or "forbidden" errors, since in that case simply nothing will happen.

Comment: @cpury So that is what I just showed you how to do in the answer. Your Messages [`.remove()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/remove) "should" be doing much the same thing rather than retrieving the document first. The UI part was just advice.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll use your solution, then. Thanks for the advice, too!